# How to position the caption of a table?

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I have a sample file of a journal and I'm writing my article in this file.

Unfortunately I couldn't bring the caption of tables to top because the position seems to be fixed in the style.

I tried some of your answers for this problem, but there was an error for each solution!

Now... how can I have a table with a justified (not centered) caption that is on the top of the table?

Comment: We would need to know the journal class you're working with (and preferably a minimal example).

Comment: I'm working with "Astrophysical Journal" (or ApJ) style. Is it enough to answer?

Comment: Ideally we'd like to also see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). And where can we find this `apj.cls`?

Comment: Actually its a long paper, but if this make a help, it is the sample file structure:

Comment: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/emulateapj.cls

Comment: if you intend to publish  your article in journal, than don't change prepared (and hard coded) article form. If this is not the case, than don't use their document class but stick with `article` and `caption`, where your problem is simple to solve.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

In order to place the caption at the top of the float, place it at the top within your code:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{<caption>}
  <table>
\end{table}
```

To remove the centering and have the `\caption` justified, you have two options:

1. Fully justify the *entire* caption. Add the following to your preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   \makeatletter
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\centering}{}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Fully justify the caption text *only*. Add the following to your preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox,ragged2e}

   \makeatletter
   % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\par}{\par\justifying}{}{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   This will keep **Table X** centred, but the caption text justified.